# How can i get python and matplotlib on my Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

Okay so I tried to install matplotlib and python earlier from the command line. Turns out i probably already had python installed but it was not make(ing) plots. Then that didn't work so i tried to, from the software center install matplotlib. So my software center says it is installed. However, when i am in python it still can not find matplotlib. Also when i am not in python and try to run commands like

```
python setup.py clean
```

It says python cannot find setup.py

This has been going on for hours and i am a beginner linux user and it is horrible

Comment: python is already installed, how did you install matplotlib?

Answer (score 4):

From the command line you can install matplotlib as follows:

```
 $ sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib
```

Once it's installed you can access it from inside python like this:

```
 >>> import matplotlib
 >>> help(matplotlib)
```

Comment: I was trying to run a make file from outside of python and was getting errors so i guess i never just imported matplotlib from inside python.

Answer (score 1):

If you want more control over the version of python you're using, I recommend using [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads). Very easy to install and use.

If you want even more control you can [build from source](http://anderspitman.com/blog/2014/06/15/setting-up-an-ipython-development-environment-from-source/). That post is specifically about setting up IPython but the python build step are the same.